# PCC - Put Data Into a Region

Tags: cloud-foundry, gemfire, geode

While using PCC, (geode/gemfire), can we insert data into regions?

Do we have any other application to browse PCC data other than pulse dashboard?

Is there an OQL to put data into the regions?

Answer (score 0):

This example application that uses PCC https://github.com/pivotal-cf/PCC-Sample-App-PizzaStore might help.

There is no support in OQL for update/insert, only select.